# What is the use of star(*) in yaml file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-boot-actuator

I was going through spring boot actuator when I stumbled upon this quote:

> `*` has a special meaning in YAML, so be sure to add quotes if you want to include (or exclude) all endpoints.

I tried to look over the internet about it without any luck. What is the use of `*` in yaml file?

Comment: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760633, https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786448. There's a spec, the word "asterisk" exists in it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`*` is used to remove the repeated nodes. Consider this yaml example:

```
myprop:
  uid: &id XXX
myprop1:
  id: *id
```

The above will expand to:

```
myprop:
  uid: XXX
myprop1:
  id: XXX
```

Now try running this code:

```
@Value("${myprop.uid}") String uid;
@Value("${myprop1.id}") String id;

@Bean
ApplicationRunner runner() {
    return args -> {
        System.out.println(uid);  // prints "XXX"
        System.out.println(id); // prints "XXX"
        System.out.println(uid.equals(id)); // prints "true"
    };
}
```

From the [spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395):

> Repeated nodes (objects) are first identified by an anchor (marked with the ampersand - “**&**”), and are then aliased (referenced with an asterisk - “***”) thereafter.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the context of the YAML file. You said you *was going through spring boot actuator*, so you can take a look into the reference documentation of Spring Boot, the chapter [5.2.2. Exposing Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) to be exact.

> `*` can be used to select all endpoints. For example, to expose everything over HTTP except the env and beans endpoints, use the following properties:
>
> ```
> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
> management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=env,beans
> ```

The asterisk `*` means that *all* the endpoints that belongs to a certain category are either included or exluded.

The sentence below just says that the asterisk `*` character must be quoted `"*"` in case of the YAML format usage over classic properties file.

> `*` has a special meaning in YAML, so be sure to add quotes if you want to include (or exclude) all endpoints, as shown in the following example:

By the way, this sentence is the **same** one you have sited at your question.

Comment: why did you pasted things from documentation itself?

Comment: To support statements in my answer through the references and citing the documentation.

Comment: How does it depend on the context of the yaml file? It always means the same thing. The stuff you posted about spring boot is irrelevant.

Comment: @123: How? The meaning of the asterisk depends on the type of properties being used. In case of Spring Boot Actuator (that one the OP is citing from) it enables all the endpoints. The sole asterisk can have a different meaning in ex. Spring Security. My question is based on the Spring Boot Actuator documentation that the OP cites, the [tag:spring], hence my answer is very relevant. Otherwise the question is unclear. I don't understand where do you aim at.

Comment: Nope it always needs to be quoted in `Yaml` files regardless of context, the snippet you've posted is a normal `.properties` file. OP wasn't asking the meaning of `*` in Spring, they were asking specifically it's purpose in Yaml files. Also I'm not the one who downvoted, since you've answered what you thought the question was. The question (to me anyway) is very clear. Just appears to be a misinterpretation possibly on your end.

Comment: IMO the question is pretty specific; OP quotes the Spring docs where it says why to quote it if it's being used as an endpoint wildcard, and is asking specifically what a `*` means in a YAML *as it pertains to YAML*. *shrug* Still doesn't merit a downvote, but AFAICT the question itself is clear.